# where in sagemaker hosted models can I apply preprocessing for the endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint

It's pretty simple to create a catboost model in sagemaker.

`tabular_estimator = Estimator( role=sagemaker_role, image_uri=train_image_uri, etc )` .
It's also fairly easy to deploy an endpoint.

But, once I've done so, it's hard to do anything else.  In my case, I'd like to some preprocessing of requests once they are received by the endpoint.

For example, if someone sends:

`{ model: 'endpoint_001', body: ["cow", "cow", "pig"]}`

how can I find the correct place to insert a python script with which I transform the request into the correct structure, aka,

`{ model: 'endpoint_001', body: ["1", "1", "2"]}`   .

that the model expects?

I've tried looking thru the plethora of outdated, unorganzied AWS docs.

Answer (score 0):

#### To achieve the transformation you described, you can do:

### 1. Create a Python script (e.g., preprocess.py):

In this script, define a function that takes the input request and performs the required transformation. Save this script, for example, as preprocess.py.

```py
def preprocess_request(request):
    # Your custom logic to transform input strings to numerical values
```

### 2. Modify the Estimator creation to include the custom script:

When creating the "Estimator" for your CatBoost model, make sure to include the preprocess.py script.

```py
tabular_estimator = Estimator(
    role=sagemaker_role,
    image_uri=train_image_uri,
    entry_point='preprocess.py',  # Specify the name of your preprocessing script
    # other parameters...
)
```

### To apply the preprocessing in the endpoint :~

You can apply preprocessing for the endpoint by utilizing the "input_fn" function. This function allows you to customize how the incoming requests are processed before being passed to the model.

### 3. Use the custom preprocessing function in input_fn:

```py
from preprocess import preprocess_request

def input_fn(request_body, request_content_type):
    # Perform preprocessing on the request_body
    processed_body = preprocess_request(request_body)

    # Return the processed input in the format expected by your model
    return processed_body, request_content_type
```

### 4. Deploy the model:

Deploy the model with the updated input_fn as before.

Hope this is find some info, if it is out of the content let me know what requires then.